constexpr in relation to memory leaks in C
I am learning C and today I wrote some code to turn roman numerals to numbers.
In my program I have a const int MAXWORTLEN = 16; inside of int main(), as well as an array of booleans, which I have declared with:
bool *vorzeichen = calloc(MAXWORTLEN, sizeof(bool));, which I free() in the end.
I am programming in CLion which sometimes gives little tips to "improve" the program like making an int into a const int if it fits the case. It also warns against memory leaks, unreachable code, etc.
By keeping my MAXWORTLEN a const int, CLion warns that "Allocated memory is leaked". By changing to constexpr int MAXWORTLEN = 16;, as it suggests, the warning goes away.
All warnings that Clion gives are:
Function 'main' always returns 0 :22
Allocated memory is leaked :29
Leak of memory allocated in function 'main' :33
Variable 'MAXWORTLEN' can be made constexpr :23

The file is a .c file. I am using build tool ninja and gcc as a C compiler.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int rom_wert(char c) {

    if(c>='a' && c<='z') {
        c = c + ('A' - 'a');
    }
    switch (c) {
        case 'I': return 1;
        case 'V': return 5;
        case 'X': return 10;
        case 'L': return 50;
        case 'C': return 100;
        case 'D': return 500;
        case 'M': return 1000;

        default: return -1;
    }
}

int main() {
    constexpr int MAXWORTLEN = 16;
    printf("Eingabe: ");

    char *eingabe = calloc(MAXWORTLEN, sizeof(char));
    scanf("%15s", eingabe);

    bool *vorzeichen = calloc(MAXWORTLEN, sizeof(bool));

    for(int i=0; eingabe[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if(rom_wert(eingabe[i]) == -1) {
            return 0;
        }
        if(rom_wert(eingabe[i]) < rom_wert(eingabe[i+1])) {
            vorzeichen[i] = true;
        }
    }

    int summe = 0;
    for(int j=0; eingabe[j] != '\0'; j++) {
        if(vorzeichen[j] == 1)
            summe = summe - rom_wert(eingabe[j]);
        else if(vorzeichen[j] == 0)
            summe = summe + rom_wert(eingabe[j]);
    }

    printf("Ausgabe: %d", summe);

    free(eingabe);
    free(vorzeichen);

    return 0;
}                                           

Where is the memory leak in the original code, and how does constexpr resolve it?
Any answer is greatly appreciated, as my only goal in this exercise is to learn :)

OT: You might be interested to learn about the toupper function.

You have early return from main before performing free. IT is probably referring to that case.

And why are you using calloc to create your arrays? Why not plain and simple arrays? No dynamic allocation means no need to free the memory, means no leaks.


Where is the memory leak in the original code

The memory leak occurs when the return 0 line is executed in the for-loop near the top of main.  The return 0 means that the rest of the function is never executed and therefore the calls to free() are never made.  (On a modern OS with resource-tracking, that doesn't much matter since the program then exits and all of its memory is automatically freed anyway, but it is still technically a leak)

and how does constexpr resolve it?

I don't think it does, but my suspicion is that tagging the variable with constexpr may have allowed the compiler/optimizer to implicitly remove the calloc() and free() calls entirely and replace them with one or more stack-based arrays instead, in which case there would be no memory leak as there was never any heap allocation to begin with.

I suspect you're right about the in-practice effect of constexpr, but I note that there's no particular reason why a compiler couldn't make the same optimization you suggest without constexpr, too.

@JohnBollinger I would be surprised if any compiler would make such an optimization as it would be tricky to determine if free were called/elided. And, it would need full call graph analysis to ensure that switching to stack allocation wouldn't overflow the stack (e.g. a called function that does a huge stack allocation that, normally, is okay but becomes overflow because of the unexpected larger stack frame for main). IMO, if a compiler did this, I'd want -fno-dont-help-me-this-way

@JohnBollinger And, the compiler would need "incestuous knowledge" of the relationship between calloc et. al. and free (to know that if converts calloc to stack allocation, it must elide the free calls). And, would it do the same for calls to my_calloc and my_free (e.g.)? How far down the rabbit hole would we need to go? And, if we do foo(eingabe), we have to disable this because we don't know what foo will do with a pointer if it expects it to be on the heap (and does free conditionally). If the programmer wants stack, just do alloca explicitly.

@CraigEstey, I feel like you're mainly addressing Jeremy.  My own primary point is that in the program presented, constexpr doesn't tell the compiler anything it didn't already know.  However, modern compilers do know about the C standard library, and they do sometimes perform optimizations that replace function calls with equivalent(-enough) other code.  I don't know whether the OP's GCC makes the particular optimization suggested, but it doesn't seem implausible to me.  Presumably, no, it would not do the same with my_calloc() and my_free().

@CraigEstey the "as if" rule is a powerful drug... it tempts every compiler-developer towards madness :)

@JohnBollinger But, you (in but it doesn't seem implausible to me) reinforced the notion that the optimization might be okay. It breaks valgrind et. al (any LD_PRELOAD that overrides calloc/free). So, nope. Jeremy: I long for the 1960s when the drug of choice was weed: A [heavy] user would just fall asleep long before the descent into madness (and wouldn't remember [to implement] it in the morning) :-)

@CraigEstey, C compilers are not obliged to accommodate Valgrind, or LD_PRELOAD or similar external facilities.  They have a very free hand when it comes to optimization.  The optimization proposed is OK.  I just don't know whether GCC is actually performing it.


Where is the memory leak in the original code

If the return in this code fragment ...

        if(rom_wert(eingabe[i]) == -1) {
            return 0;
        }


... is executed, then control leaves main() without either allocated block being freed.  This is presumably what CLion's complains about, though in most operating environments, this particular kind of "leak" is benign: the OS will generally clean up any memory still allocated when the program terminates.

, and how does constexpr resolve it?

Declaring variables as constexpr does not resolve it.  I cannot speak to why CLion that affects whether CLion presents the diagnostic.  Moreover, I can't say I much care for CLion's recommendation to declare MAXWORTLEN as constexpr.  Doing so yields no particular advantage I can see, and reduces your program's compatibility with older C compilers, as constexpr was not introduced into standard C until C23, which was published only a few weeks ago..
